# Get result from listener async

Tags: node.js, async-await, puppeteer, eventemitter, puppeteer-cluster

I use puppeteer-cluster + node js. I am new in that.
I have some trouble.
I need to get XHR response from site.I am listening to the page, but I cannot write the resulting value to the variable. I need to use the value in another part of the code.
how to wait for the function to execute in a listener and write the result to a variable?

```
dataCreation = [];
function get_data (data){
 dataCreation [id] = data;}
await page.on('response', async (response) =>{
  if (response.url === 'your_url'){ 
    let XHR_response = await response.json();
    let array_lenght = (XHR_response).length;
    let data2 = XHR_response.objects[array_lenght-1].creationDate;
    get_data(data2);}});

await console.log(dataCreation [id];
```

But dataCreation [id] is undefeated. Because i need to await listener and get result from it. How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: What’s with the invalid syntax at `await console.log(dataCreation [id];`?

Comment: sorry, there are ) in my cod. i did mistake only here, then do post in stackoverflow. Thank you

Comment: [Edit] your question. Your question is supposed to have a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
    const XHR_response = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      page.on('response', checkResponse);

      function checkResponse(response) {
        if (response.url() === 'your_url') {
          page.off('response', checkResponse);
          resolve(response.json());
        }
      }
    });

    let array_lenght = XHR_response.objects.length;
    let data2 = XHR_response.objects[array_lenght-1].creationDate;
    get_data(data2);

    console.log(dataCreation[id]);
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was a typo)